# mobile navigation not showing submenu

Tags: navigation, menu, mobile, rwd

I am using "Argento" theme which is using tm navigation pro extension to display top navigation. I used the following script for top navigtion.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
    navPro("navigationpro-top", {
        show_delay: 100,
        hide_delay: 100,
        dropdown_side: "right"
    });
});
new accordion('navigationpro-top');
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">

document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {
    $('nav-top-toggle').observe('click', function() {
        $('nav-top-toggle').next().toggleClassName('shown');
    });
    new MobileNavigation();

    $('mobile-navigation-toggle').observe('click', function() {
        $('nav-top-toggle').next().toggleClassName('shown');
    });

});
</script>
```

The problem is if i click the mobile togglers it only shows main menu only. I couldn't track what i am missing. How to fix this?

Comment: Were you able to find the solution? I am having a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the navigation menu and look for the css file responsible for it's style. Likely something like:

`skin/frontend/yourtheme/default/css/theme.css`

Make sure that there is no rule for desktop only on the navigation menu.